# ClassNotFoundException when running outside IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, classnotfoundexception

I have a java application which was developed in Eclipse.

There is a folder on the system which contains a lot of ".java" files. These ".java" files are classes which some user has written. I wish to load all these java classes and compile them inside my java application.

Another property of all the ".java" files are that all the classes written inside extend a class which is inside my original application.

I used the following to read and compile all the classes.

```
File parentFile = new File(rulesDir + "\\");
String fileName = rulesDir + "\\" + ruleName + ".java";
File ruleFile = new File(fileName);
// Compile source file.
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null, ruleFile.getPath());             
// Load and instantiate compiled class.
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { parentFile.toURI().toURL() });
Class<? extends AbstractRule> cls = (Class<? extends AbstractRule>)Class.forName(ruleName, true, classLoader);
```

If I run the above code inside Eclipse, it works fine. When I run the application as a jar from elsewhere, it throws an `ClassNotFoundException` for the line 
`Class<? extends AbstractRule> cls = (Class<? extends AbstractRule>)Class.forName(ruleName, true, classLoader);`

Why is this happening? What is different that it executes in Eclipse and doesn't via command line?

Comment: Is the IDE that is being used in Eclipse the same version as that from where you run the JAR?
To check your Eclipse JRE: click "Window" then "Preferences", under Java in the Preferences menu select Installed JREs.

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis before Class.forName. Typo?

Comment: Edited. That was a typo. No syntax errors in eclipse

Comment: Consider reading the stdout and stderr of the [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/Tool.html#run(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String...)) to assure that compilation is occurring correctly.

Comment: Your classpath to your rule is not fully qualified. I just tried it and created a directory for my rules called rules. Which also contains AbstractRule. And the class is only loaded correctly when I refer to the fully qualified classname of rules.TestRule, rather than just TestRule. As per docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader). Not sure why it's working in Eclipse, but you must have a classpath defined somewhere, or the rulesDir is simply an empty string or something.

Comment: Replace the backslashes in your rulesDir with periods and ensure there's a period at the end. Then prepend that to your ruleName in your Class.forName call and it works as expected.

Comment: rulesDir contains something like this C://Users//abc//Desktop @ManoDestra

Comment: AbstractRule class is not contained in the rules folder. It is part of the original java application. @ManoDestra

Comment: let me try your suggestion

Comment: Doesn't really matter about AbstractRule being in the spec. The principle is the same. Your subclass can't be found as you're not referring to it correctly. You need to refer to it from the root of your classpath by its fully qualified name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Class.forName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader))

> name - fully qualified name of the desired class

So, in order to get that fully qualified class name, you need to manipulate your rulesDir variable to replace the backslashes with periods, then prepend that to your ruleName variable, combined with another period, to get the fully qualified class name. Then you'll be able to use the ClassLoader to load the class. The fully qualified name is required so that the ClassLoader can find your resource from the root of your classpath.

**NB I make the assumption that your rulesDir is a relative path from the base of your classpath. If it is not, then you'll have extra manipulation to do here**

See code manipulation below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import rules.AbstractRule;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Test");
            // NB Amended here to now take project root, relative path to rules directory and class name. So that compilation can take place based on the absolute path and class loading from the relative one.
            compile("C:\\Media\\Code\\manodestra_java\\src\\tmp", "rules", "TestRule");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void compile(String projectRoot, String rulesDir, String ruleName) throws Exception {
        File parentFile = new File(projectRoot + "\\" + rulesDir + "\\");
        System.out.println(parentFile);
        String fileName = parentFile.getCanonicalPath() + "\\" + ruleName + ".java";
        File ruleFile = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println(ruleFile);

        // Compile source file.
        System.out.println("Compiling...");
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, ruleFile.getPath());

        // Load and instantiate compiled class.
        System.out.println("Loading class...");
        URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { parentFile.toURI().toURL() });
        System.out.println("Class Loader: " + classLoader);
        ruleName = rulesDir.replace("\\", ".") + "." + ruleName;
        Class<? extends AbstractRule> clazz = (Class<? extends AbstractRule>)Class.forName(ruleName, true, classLoader);
        System.out.println(clazz);
    }
}
```

For the sake of my testing, this class was defined in the default package and I created a rules directory below that level to contain my subclasses of AbstractRule. So, `rules.TestRule` was my fully qualified path to my class name. But, yours could be...

> com.example.testapplication.rules.TestRule, etc.

And that's what would be required in Class.forName. There's a path to your classpath root, then the relative path from there to your java files (which is equivalent to the package of your classes), then the actual class names under that package path.

Comment: Sorry. The assumption you have is not correct. RulesDir is an absolute path. Not a relative path. How would we solve this situation? @ManoDestra

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It now doesnt work on eclipse and the command line. But I think that is because of the assumption that rulesDir is a relative path.

Comment: I've described in the answer how to resolve that situation. You can point at your absolute path for compilation, but you need to point at the fully qualified path for Class.forName, which will be a period delimited subset of the absolute path.

Comment: You should know the root of your project. For compilation: `projectRoot + "\\" + rulesDir + "\\" + ruleName + ".java"` (where project is absolute path to root of your classpath and rulesDir is relative from there to your rules directory. Then you can follow what I've done above regarding altering the relative rulesDir to get your fully qualified name. And if your rules are in the root, then you may have to remove the initial ., as well as the rulesDir transformation.

Comment: Updated my answer with new code that shows the new loading using projectRoot, rulesDir and ruleName. Project root is absolute to project root, rulesDir is relative from that directory and ruleName is within the rules dir (combination of projectRoot + rulesDir).

Comment: Okay to understand : If I have a class called ABC.java located in "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Rules\ABC.java". Then what is the fully qualified name of this class?

Comment: Depends on the root of your project. If your project root is C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Rules, then its fully qualified path is simply ABC. You should have your rules folder held somewhere within your project. So, I would expect to see C:\Users\user1\Desktop\projects\testproject\src\main\java\com\test\rules\ABC.java. Your class path root in that instance would be C:\Users\user1\Desktop\projects\testproject\src\main\java. Your rules directory would then be com\test\rules and your class name is ABC.java. And hence its fully qualified path is com.test.rules.ABC.

Comment: If you look in your ABC.java class, it will have a package defined it. Use that plus your class name to construct the fully qualified path. If there's no package defined, then it's in the default package and the fully qualified path is simply the class name.

Comment: Why should the rules folder be held somewhere within the project? I am getting the path to where the rules folder is when the jar is called through the command line

Comment: If it isn't, then you still need to refer to your class files via their fully qualified class name regardless. So, if your package is `com.example.rules` and you have a class called `ExampleRule` designated as being in that package, then you need to refer to it, when loading, as `com.example.rules.ExampleRule` regardless of its location in your file system. Make sense? And if this Java file is not inside a known project, then why not? Makes no real sense to have random Java files located on your file system that aren't part of a project that will be built in a managed fashion.